# How to reset sort and filter at the same time with AG Grid

Tags: ag-grid

I'd like to be able to reset all filters and sorts at the same time without triggering two different refreshes of the table. I'm using the infinite model so if I can't batch the change, it results in two requests to the database.

Here's what I do currently:

```
            api.setFilterModel(null);
            api.applyColumnState({
                defaultState: { sort: null },
            });
```

Is there a way to batch these changes to avoid the double-fetch?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to define gridRef like that

```
const gridRef = useRef(null)
```

and give it to agGrid

```
<AgGridReact
  ref={gridRef}
  ...other props
  />
```

then after you have to use your filter and sort like that way. It will reset your grid

```
 gridRef?.current?.columnApi.resetColumnState();
```